# "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" after calling an async operation

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am getting the following error in Orchard CMS v1.6

**"The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction"**

in an Asynchronous ApiController in Orchard CMS. But once replacing the async call to a synchronous calls, it is working fine.

Does Orchard does not support async apicontrollers? Is there any workaround for it? 
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

The stack trace is as follow,

```
[TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.]
   System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction) +53
   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistVolatile(IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions) +292
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory.EnlistInDistributedTransactionIfNeeded(ISessionImplementor session) +457
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Batcher() +23
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) +544
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +273
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +205
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +196

[GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.Id as Id272_3_, this_.Number as Number272_3_, this_.Published as Published272_3_, this_.Latest as Latest272_3_, this_.Data as Data272_3_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_272_3_, contentite1_.Id as Id271_0_, contentite1_.Data as Data271_0_, contentite1_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_271_0_, sitesettin4_.Id as Id286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteSalt as SiteSalt286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteName as SiteName286_1_, sitesettin4_.SuperUser as SuperUser286_1_, sitesettin4_.PageTitleSeparator as PageTitl5_286_1_, sitesettin4_.HomePage as HomePage286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteCulture as SiteCult7_286_1_, sitesettin4_.ResourceDebugMode as Resource8_286_1_, sitesettin4_.PageSize as PageSize286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteTimeZone as SiteTim10_286_1_, contenttyp5_.Id as Id273_2_, contenttyp5_.Name as Name273_2_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id left outer join Settings_SiteSettingsPartRecord sitesettin4_ on contentite1_.Id=sitesettin4_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp5_ on contentite1_.ContentType_id=contenttyp5_.Id WHERE contentite1_.Id = ? and this_.Published = ? ]
  Name:cp0 - Value:1  Name:cp1 - Value:True
[SQL: SELECT this_.Id as Id272_3_, this_.Number as Number272_3_, this_.Published as Published272_3_, this_.Latest as Latest272_3_, this_.Data as Data272_3_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_272_3_, contentite1_.Id as Id271_0_, contentite1_.Data as Data271_0_, contentite1_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_271_0_, sitesettin4_.Id as Id286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteSalt as SiteSalt286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteName as SiteName286_1_, sitesettin4_.SuperUser as SuperUser286_1_, sitesettin4_.PageTitleSeparator as PageTitl5_286_1_, sitesettin4_.HomePage as HomePage286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteCulture as SiteCult7_286_1_, sitesettin4_.ResourceDebugMode as Resource8_286_1_, sitesettin4_.PageSize as PageSize286_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteTimeZone as SiteTim10_286_1_, contenttyp5_.Id as Id273_2_, contenttyp5_.Name as Name273_2_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id left outer join Settings_SiteSettingsPartRecord sitesettin4_ on contentite1_.Id=sitesettin4_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp5_ on contentite1_.ContentType_id=contenttyp5_.Id WHERE contentite1_.Id = ? and this_.Published = ?]]
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +642
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +23
   NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session) +60
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) +1039
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) +63
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List() +79
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetManyImplementation(QueryHints hints, Action`2 predicate) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:334
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:140
   Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentGetExtensions.Get(IContentManager manager, Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:160
   Orchard.Core.Settings.Services.SiteService.GetSiteSettings() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Services\SiteService.cs:46
   Orchard.Settings.CurrentSiteWorkContext.Get(String name) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Settings\CurrentSiteWorkContext.cs:13
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +111
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +215
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.FindResolverForState(String name) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:32
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +79
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState(String name) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:28
   Orchard.Roles.Services.RolesBasedAuthorizationService.TryCheckAccess(Permission permission, IUser user, IContent content) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Roles\Services\RolesBasedAuthorizationService.cs:50
   Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:72
   Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Security\SecurityFilter.cs:24
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +714
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\292d2471f57b6038\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:163
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1799
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +3300
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +1536
```

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous operations in Orchard 1.6 do not work because they use [`TranscactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from [`System.Transcations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Transactions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [`TranscactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) must be finished in the same thread that was created, and async operations do not offer this.
Probably you need to upgrade Orchard (to 1.7) or change the implementation ITranscationManager and ISessionLocator.

Comment: Yeah I pretty much agree to the answer you provided, the project is sort of huge, so on the process of upgrading to 1.7. But few problems what I faced in the MVC Async Controller of Orchard was the HttpContext was always null as it was not thread safe. I am quite convinced that it would be resolved in v1.7. But will give a try and thanks for the answer. Will mark as Accepted Answer after upgrading the version in the next 2 days :).

Comment: Upgrade to v1.7 but made no differences on Async calls. But probably try to update the implementation of ITransactionManager and see if it makes any difference.